# customWebpackConfig not working in ng build --prod in Angular

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to remove unnecessary Cypress attributes from html files in Angular 7 application.

I found this [SOLUTION](https://medium.com/agilix/angular-and-cypress-data-cy-attributes-d698c01df062)

So I added to my `angular.json`:

```
"build": {
  "builder": "angular-cli-builders:custom-webpack-browser",
  "options": {
    "customWebpackConfig": {
      "path": "./webpack/webpack.extra.js",
      "mergeStrategies": {
        "externals": "append"
      }
    },
```

and attributes are removed when I use `ng build`, but when I'll use `ng build --prod` then attributes are not removed, why?

I was trying to add it here too, no success:

```
 "configurations": {
   "production": {
     "customWebpackConfig": { [...]
```

Comment: Check this answer to see if you configure your angular.json file correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72423671/6666348

Answer (score 0):

`@angular-builders/custom-webpack` has four options depending on your build (universal, dev, etc).  It is actually quite easy once you read [these simple instructions](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack).

Answer (score -1):

The [solution on Medium](https://medium.com/agilix/angular-and-cypress-data-cy-attributes-d698c01df062) referenced in this question is out of date for Angular 8+.

Firstly, the `angular-cli-builders` npm package is deprecated. You will need the version of [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) that is appropriate for your Angular version instead.

Then, if your builds are using ahead-of-time compilation - which most production configurations will - then it is very difficult to intercept and replace the `data-cy` attributes within source .html files.  The only way I could reliably get this to work was to examine the built .js output, and replace the attributes within there instead.

Here's the relevant parts of a working `angular.json` file for Angular 9:

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "datacy": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "sourceMap": true,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "customWebpackConfig": {
                "path": "./webpack-config.prod.ts",
                "mergeStrategies": {
                  "module.rules": "prepend"
                }
              },
              "optimization": true,
              "aot": true,
              ...
```

webpack.config.prod.ts

```ts
import * as path from 'path';
import * as webpack from 'webpack';

export default {
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: [{ loader: path.resolve('./data-cy-loader.ts') }],
    }],
  },
} as webpack.Configuration;
```

data-cy-loader.ts

```ts
/*
  HTML formatting looks like <element data-cy="value">
  Inlined within a javascript string, it looks like <element data-cy=\"value\">

  Compiled AOT, the element attributes are turned into an array:
    [["class", "cssClassName"], ["data-cy", "value"], ...]

  The data-cy attribute may appear at the start, middle, or end of this array.
*/
export default (source: string) => {
  if (source.indexOf('data-cy') >= 0) {
    return source.replace(/\["data-cy" ?,"([^"]*)"\],/g, '')              // ["data-cy", "..."], variants
                 .replace(/, ?\["data-cy", ?"([^"]*)"\]/g, '')            // , ["data-cy", "..."]] variant
                 .replace(/(\[")?data-cy(=|(",))\\?"([^"]*)"(\])?/g, ''); // [["data-cy","..."]] and html variants
  }
  return source;
};
```