# How to see webpack config from angular application?

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

I create angular application using `ng new my-app` command.

How I can see `webpack.config` that Angular built for my app? I don't want to customize this webpack config. just to log it to file/screen...

Answer (score 2):

`Angular` core **webpack config** is placed in `node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/webpack/configs/browser.js` and you can change the parameters there.

Suggestion is to create a `patch.js` file to change the file after every `npm update` to prevent rewriting codes.

And if you are talking about the `webpack` to use in building your additional package you have to create config file yourself and reference that in `angular.json`

#### Update:

In the earlier versions of Angular, this file is placed in the following path `node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/builders/browser-esbuild/index.js`.

Comment: It's a bad idea to patch original Angular configuration. Much better and cleaner way is to use a custom builder with custom webpack config (this one looks most popular and known - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) or create your own custom builder (https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-customize-an-angular-project-build-2e7e2c31ca6b)

Comment: I did it in our team which develop an enterprise application in a banking industry and it worked fine for 5 new developers we hired without any documentation or anything. I just put the patch file runner in `postinstall` script. @vlad2135

Comment: Are you sure about "browser.js" file? I don't have such file inside "configs"...

Comment: what is your angular version? @Alexander

Comment: @MahdiZarei it's 15

Comment: @Alexander from angular 13 (or 12 I can't remember correctly) this file is placed in the following path `node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/builders/browser-esbuild/index.js`

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to have a **custom webpack** config file like you and implement it as below:

1. Install custom-webpack library

   ```
   npm i -D @angular-builders/custom-webpack
   ```
2. Add the following configurations to angular.json file

   ```
   "architect": {
       ...
       "build": {
           "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
           "options": {
               "customWebpackConfig": {
                   "path": "./webpack.config.js"
               },
            ...
        }
   }
   ```
3. If your project configured with angular universal (SSR) then you should add following configurations in your angular.json file too:

   ```
   "architect": {
       ...
       "serve": {
         "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
         "options": {
             "customWebpackConfig": {
             "path": "./webpack.config.js"
         }
     }
     ...
   ```

   }
4. Create **webpack.config.js** in the root of your application project and write your custom webpack configurations in it